# Rails 4 - App works locally, but not on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, compatibility

In my app, I'm using the [cocoon gem](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon) to dynamically add/remove nested form fields. The problem I am experiencing is that it works perfectly in my development environment, but when I push to Heroku, that piece of functionality doesn't work. To clarify what I mean, the link to add a form field simply doesn't do anything.

```
<%= link_to_add_association "Add URL", f, :mozs %>
```

Now, I am making the assumption that since it works locally, that my code is correct and nothing is wrong there. What I would like to know is why might I experience this issue between dev and production? What could be different between the two environments that might cause this?

I know Heroku uses the rails_12factor gem, which I have set to use in production. Could this be a potential conflict with the cocoon gem that I am using?

(Note: I'm not sure what other useful information I can provide. Please let me know if there is anything else that would be useful for me to include.)

Comment: did you do `rake assets:precompile` ?

Comment: do you have `config.serve_static_assets = true` in `config/environments.production.rb`

Comment: `gem 'rails_12factor'` in production is not conflicting `cocoon`. I have used it with `cocoon` and is working fine.

Comment: @WaliAli It looks like it was `rake assets:precompile` that was needed. However, I had to remove 'require self` and `require_tree .` in application.css to successfully run it. Otherwise rake aborts with Invalid CSS error from fontawesome.

Comment: Cool. I'm glad it you got it working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't forget `rake assets:precompile`. In the case of rake aborting from invalid css, check the `bootstrap_and_overrides.css` for any added less code. I've noticed that generating this from the twitter-bootstrap-rails gem has in the past done this to me.